# Is there any git command to display the information about local branch?

Tags: git

For example, if I am branch `A`, and created new branch `B` with the command

`git checkout -b B`

is there any way that sometimes later I can find out where branch B copied from?? (A) in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do `git merge-base branchX branchY` that will give you the common parent.  That will tell you *when* it split off the branch, but there is no way to tell *who* it split off of.

Comment: I would argue that the one who split the branch off is the first committer on branch B after the merge-base.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `gitk`?

> Displays changes in a repository or a selected set of commits. This includes visualizing the commit
>          graph, showing information related to each commit, and the files in the trees of each revision.

The various branches and tags are highlighted in the tree.

Comment: What if it was split off a branch that was deleted?  What if it split off a branch that was renamed? What if the branch it split  off of, later split into multiple branches?  There is no way for git to *KNOW* that branch x came from branch y.

Comment: You are right, git can't know there existed some branch with that name if its deleted/renamed.

Answer (score 0):

There no tracking of which branch was created from which, and the commits that each branch point to could change at any time.

But this might do what you need:

```
git branch --merged B
```

That will show the list of all branches that are ancestors of branch B.  So if you are on branch B, it will show branch A until there are commits made to A that fork it off--then it will no longer show A unless you merge A back into B, then it will show A again.