# How to revert changes I made with merging two branches

Tags: git

I have two branches `develop` and `personal`. I use `GitExtensions` tool. I was working in `develop` branch and then I needed to merge it with `personal`. I launched merging, the tool notified me there are some conflicts (different name of packages) and proposed to resolve conflicts using `mergetool`. But `mergetool` wasn't opened as usual but I got the message all conflict resolved, I was expecting to resolve them manually. Of course this accidentally (?) happened merging was incorrect and I tried to revert these changes by `Reset current branch to here` and chosen my previous commit. Unfortunately changes made were reverted (which is ok) but **name of folders** (my packages in android platform) didn't. I tried to revert changes by `checkout` and `reset` but I can't get the snapshot of file system when everything was ok. I'm very new to `git`, please advice how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you do a `hard` reset?  In git extensions you tick the checkbox that says `hard`

If you reset your branch to a commit before the changes, everything should have reset to to *exactly* what was in your repository at that commit.  If you're saying folder names are not correct, are you sure they were being tracked at that point in time?  You can find out if they are being tracked at that time by running `git ls-files`

If they are being tracked at the time, try running `git reset --hard`, after you reset back to that point.  Any unsaved changes you have to tracked files will be lost forever when you do this, so make sure you have everything committed, or `git stash` your changes.

Comment: You right, they weren't tracked according to `git ls-files`. I don't know how this happened. I renamed them the other day and committed these renames. Also my source files were in these renamed folders. Now files are in place, but in not renamed folders. Very very odd, I cant wrap my head over this shit.

Comment: Look at the commit where you committed your renames and see if you actually did commit them.  What does `git status` say?  are there pending renames?

Comment: Is that possible to find the moment when I created 'personal' branch?

Comment: You can look at your tree in git extensions and the first commit after the split is when it was created.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878014/is-there-any-git-command-to-display-the-information-about-local-branch/6878198#6878198) is how you can tell when a branch split off another branch.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the branch you want to revert then using git log get the hash of a commit corresponding to the state you want. 
Then you may use git reset HASH or git chevkout HASH to revert to that commit